# Remove glued down carpet before installing LVP or install on top of carpet?

Tags: adhesive, carpet, vinyl-flooring

I have carpet that was glued down on a plywood subfloor. Should I lay LVP on top of the carpet or remove the carpet?
If I remove the carpet should I try to remove the glue or lay paper on top of it?
I have removed the carpet and scraped up glue in another room. The LVP still sticks to patches of glue and makes an annoying noise when stepping on it.
What is best to keep the LVP from sticking to patches of glue?

Comment: I don't know the right approach, but I'm pretty sure laying down anything on top of carpet is the wrong one. I can imagine that carpet will retain moisture pretty efficiently, which is a recipe for trouble down the road.

Comment: 99.99% of the LVP flooring I've heard about requires a stable, _flat_ (not level) surface to install. Generally, I believe it's less than 1/8" dip or bump. Unless your carpet is literally nothing but threadbare backing, it will not meet this criteria. You certainly _can_ install over that, but it will unlock itself (if it's a click-lock type) and/or simply break pretty quickly.

Comment: Well, laying the LVP on top of the carpet would give you a sprung floor! :)

Answer (score 2):

Floating floor? Lay down red rosin paper (after taking the carpet off).  Trying to get the glue off is a huge mess and you may end up damaging the floor.

Comment: Yes, something thin to prevent the glue from sticking. Some LVP manufacturers require one to use their special (and expensive!) underlayment to keep the warranty.